# Is it possible to modify Ubuntu 18.10 System Monitor to include GPU statistics?

Tags: linux, gpu

I think I can throw together a fairly simple script to poll the usage data every few seconds. I am fluent enough with node/react that I could get that data and display it in a live graph that polls asynchronously.

I've never delved into the OS like this before and I dont know how to go about adding that to the native environment. Not sure where to find the files I need to modify-- or add to. Or if I can even do that. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction please?

Comment: The question is clear. He needs 'apt source systemmonitor'

Comment: First, I think your title does not reflect what you are asking for afterwards. Could you change one or the other so your question clear? Second, what brand of GPUs?